# подзапрос SELECT в условии IN

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE books (ID integer primary key, book_id integer(20), book_name text );
INSERT INTO books (ID,book_id,book_name) VALUES (
  '1',
  '1',
  'Книга 1'
),(
  '2',
  '2',
  'Книга 2'
); 
CREATE TABLE users (ID integer primary key, user test, books_id text );
INSERT INTO users (ID,user,books_id) VALUES (
  '1',
  'Bob',
  '1,2'
);
```

Я хочу подтянуть к информации юзеров названия книг, которые в таблице users перечислены в виде id

Запрос

```
SELECT books_id FROM users WHERE id = 1
```

вернет мне значение 1,2

Запрос

```
SELECT usr.*, GROUP_CONCAT(book.book_name) AS books_name FROM users usr JOIN books book ON book.book_id IN (1,2)
```

вернет мне то, что я ожидаю увидеть - в поле books_name будут перечислены названия книг

Но их комбинация не вернет ничего

```
SELECT usr.*, GROUP_CONCAT(book.book_name) AS books_name FROM users usr JOIN books book ON book.book_id IN (SELECT books_id FROM users WHERE id = 1)
```

либо вернет неполные данные.

Что я упускаю?

Comment: У вас поле **books_id** хранит строку, и последний селект не найдет строки '1,2' в ключах таблицы books. Либо разбирайте books_id на ключи, либо меняйте формат записи взятых пользователем книг. Я бы сделал отельную сущность вида takedBooks куда положил бы id пользователя и id кники, ну и доп поля, когда взяли, когда вернули, когда надо вернуть, просрочка с возвратом...

Comment: упускаете теорию реляционных баз данных и правила нормализации данных  в частности. SQL тут уже вторичен

Comment: ``.. JOIN ON FIND_IN_SET(book.book_id, users.books_id) ..``. Но лучше всё же нормализовать.